# Using Passsource.com to create Passbook Pages Unable to Change icons

Tags: ios

I am using Passsource.com to create Passbook pages. I download the pkpass file and then I change the extension to zip. Once, the zip is created I unzip file and see the contents. I can see the icon, icon@2x, logo and logo@2x files. I replace those files with my own logo files.

Then I change the extension back to pkpass. Once, I do that I am not able to open the file in my iPhone. Any ideas on how to change the icons etc using Passsource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `manifest.json` file in the pass contains a `SHA-1` hash of every file in the Pass. When you modify the images, you are invalidating that hash – and the OS relies on it. You need to generate a new hash and include it in the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you know anyway I can change the images when using Passsource.com OR how do I create a new hash?

Comment: From the Passsource FAQ (https://www.passsource.com/faq.php): "Personal and Professional accounts have access to a template editor which allows changing of all images."

Comment: Thanks again! I will create an account and see the details.

Comment: I think it requires a paid subscription to change the images. Even in their free account there is no option to change the images.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there.